# Vim calling command on save

Tags: vim

I am trying to call [this](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat) autoformatting plugin on save

Here is my autocommand:

```
autocmd BufWrite *.css,*.html,*.js,*.py :Autoformat<CR>
```

When I save nothing happens, if I manually call :Autoformat then the autoformatter runs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already found the solution - here's the explanation:

The `<CR>` is for *mappings*, which work like a recorded sequence of typed keys, so you need to start command-line mode with `:` and conclude with `<CR>`. An autocmd takes an *Ex command*, so the `<CR>` is taken as an (invalid) argument. You also don't need the `:`, but that doesn't do harm.

As `:help BufWrite` shows, this is a synonym for `BufWritePre`.

> ```
>   BufWrite or BufWritePre     Before writing the whole buffer to a file.
> ```

So, this is the recommended form:

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.css,*.html,*.js,*.py Autoformat
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I've experienced, you sometimes need to surround it in an `augroup`

```
augroup autoFormat
    autocmd BufWrite *.css,*.html,*.js,*.py :Autoformat<CR>
augroup END
```

I don't know why but it works for me! Technically just the `autocmd` should work on its own but sometimes it doesn't. Also, on the GitHub page it says to use `:Autoformat<CR><CR>`, maybe try that.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason i had to get rid of the carriage return and change to BufWritePre (although the CR is the main issue, the BufWritePre just makes sure it gets changed before the buffer is written instead of after so it gets saved):

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.css,*.html,*.js,*.py :Autoformat
```

Why, I don't know?

Comment: Vimscript is mysterious. Maybe it performs the changes from Autoformat, but then it writes the old buffer to the file after when you use BufWrite